# How to force load and item by key in form?

Tags: datasource, google-app-maker

**The case**

1 - I have an accordion widget with datasource Tasks.
2. - I have a form to display info on a selected Task. It has a datasource TaskByKey.

**The sought solution:**

- There is a button on both Tasks AccordionRow.
- onClick the button should, based on the Key of the item of the AccordionRow load its data in the form with datasource TaskByKey.

**What I tried:**

I tried implementing the solution given as an example in Google's template, Project Tracker:

```
/**
 * Navigates user to the specific project view page.
 * @param {!string} projectKey - project key to view.
 * @param {boolean=} forceReplace - optional flag that forces to replace URL
 *     state in cases when state push would be normally used.
 */
function gotoViewProjectPageByKey(projectKey, forceReplace) {
  var params = {
    projectKey: projectKey
  };

  gotoViewProjectPageByParams(params, forceReplace);
}
```

Of course the above example targets a page, where as I want to change the datasource of an element on the same page.

**TLDR**

How can I set the onClick event of a button to load an item by key from datasource_X to datasource_X_byKey?

Comment: I assume your **TaskByKey** datasource is using a query builder. Right?

Comment: @Morfinismo No, it does not. Should it and how? I have not idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that your **TaskByKey** pretends to filter only a specific task... you can put the following on the **onClick** event of the button.

```
var taskKey = widget.datasource.item._key;
var ds = app.datasources.TaskByKey;
ds.query.filters._key._equals = taskKey;
ds.load();
//Then, here you either navigate to a page or open a dialog or open a popup.
```

The above will work considering that your **Tasks** datasource and your **TaskByKey** datasource come from the same model.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Query

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I tried to implement it, but I receive an error.

I set the onClick event to:

var taskKey = widget.datasource.item-_key;
var ds = app.datasources.TaskByKey;
ds.query.filters._key._equals = taskKey;
ds.load();

The console message is the following:
_key is not defined

I am unsure of what I've missed.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer... it shoud be `var taskKey = widget.datasource.item._key`

Comment: Works perfectly! I don't see what the typo was but it works! I am most thankful! Have a great weekend, Morfinismo!

Comment: @VesoYanchev, the typo was using a `-` instead of the `.`. Anyways, please check the documentation reference when you get a chance. That way you get to understand things better. Have a nice weekend too!